# Remove a bootstrap attribute?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am using a bootstrap class that is used un ul/li items. I have made a script that adds a border around an li item if it is clicked. The first list item is highlighted on all 4 sides when clicked, however, the rest of the list only has 3 sides highlighted. The class being used is "list-group-item" and has "border-top-width: 0;". When I disable this feature via inspect page, the bottom 2 li items work. I want to remove this feature from the class so all li items are highlighted. I have tried overriding the class with "border-top-width: none;" but no luck[image: removing border-top-width]

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned you tried overriding, but may I suggest that you !important in your border-top-width section. So like this: `border-top-width: none !important;`

Comment: that did not work unfortunately. I am not the most experienced in css, but I noticed there is a difference in the classes. At least with the first li item. Although they all are the same class, the first li is ".list-group-item:first-child" but the other li classes are ".list-group-item+.list-group-item". What do the "+" and ":" mean?